# How to configure Qt Creator for Android development on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: android, qt-creator, ubuntu-22.04

I have a problem configuring Qt Creator with Android - I'd like to be able to build a Qt-based mobile application for Android devices.

My environment:

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04 (a virtual machine running on Windows 11 via Oracle
  VM VirtualBox)
- Qt 5.15.3
- Oracle Java JDK 1.8.0 u391
- Qt Creator 6.0.2
- Android Studio 2023.1.1.26

When I point Qt Creator (in *Tools > Options > Devices > Android > Android SDK location*) to Android Studio's SDK folder (~/Android/Sdk), the following options fail:

- SDK manager runs (SDK Tools versions <= 26.x require exactly Java 1.8)
- Platform SDK installed
- All essential packages installed for all installed Qt version

[image: Failed Android SDK elements]

although I've installed the following packages from Android Studio's SDK Manager:

- SDK Platforms:

  - Android 14.0
  - Android 13.0
- SDK Tools

  - Android SDK Build-Tools 34
  - Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)
  - Android Emulator
  - Android SDK Platform-Tools 34.0.5
  - Android SDK Tools (Obsolete) 26.1.1

When I try to run SDK Manager manually:

```
cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin
./sdkmanager
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 5 more
```

On the other hand, when I point to a SDK folder created by Qt Creator (using *"Set Up SDK"* button), where SDK manager has a green tick mark, I can't install any platform tools, build tools or platform SDK, as running

```
cd ~/AndroidQt/SDK/tools/bin
./sdkmanager "build-tools;30.0.2" "ndk;21.3.6528147" "platforms;android-30" "cmdline-tools;latest"
```

results in

```
Warning: Could not create settings
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.<init>(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:428)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:152)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:134)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:57)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
```

How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. Installation of the new JDK from https://adoptium.net/ and selection it in JDK location fixed it.